# How do I find an index of an element without using the index method?

Tags: list, python-3.x, indexing

The method that I came up with doesn't work.

```
first_list = ['one', 'abra', 'kadabra']
user_input = int(input("Find index: "))

if user_input <= (len(first_list)):
    print(first_list[:])
```

I'm trying to wrap my head around it but I'm having a hard time figuring this out. Should I write a for loop that searches for a given index?

Comment: You're supposed to *take* an element and *find* its index, not *take* an index and *find*... something.

Comment: You will need a `for` loop.

Comment: are you looking for `print(first_list[user_input])`?

Comment: Thank you so much trincot! That definitely fixed what I was trying to do. What I'm trying to figure out now is a way to find the index of an element that exists in the list. So the user would ask "abra" and it would say "index 1"